# When using JQuery html() it returns the contents before using Ajax changing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a  div to hold article content and it could be changed with ajax.

I need the content in this div and I use jquery function html() to do that, but it can only fetch the content before changing.

How can I get the immediate content using jquery?

**Update:**

It runs well in my own page and the problem comes with 'share it to facebook' button script from other sites.

This is an example script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
(function(){
  var _w = 72 , _h = 16;
  var param = {
    url:'dachaocai.com/bench/2',
    type:'3',
    count:'1', 
    appkey:'', 
    title:$('#title').html()+'(Bench->'+$('#b_name').html()+')'+'http://www.dachaocai.com/bench/2', 
    pic:'', 
    ralateUid:'', 
    rnd:new Date().valueOf()
  }
  var temp = [];
  for( var p in param ){
    temp.push(p + '=' + encodeURIComponent( param[p] || '' ) )
  }
  document.write('<iframe allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://hits.sinajs.cn/A1/weiboshare.html?' + temp.join('&') + '" width="'+ _w+'" height="'+_h+'"></iframe>')
})()
</script>
```

I use html() to get the article title to share but it's always the old one.
Any way to solve this?

Comment: You probably need to put `.html` inside the ajax callback. Could you show some code please?

Comment: Please post your code - or better, set up a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Did any of these answers help?

Comment: Sorry for my late response.：）your answer did help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jquery to do an asynchronous call to a server then in the callback you can append some Html to a div.  I hope this helps.  If you post some code I can update the answer.

**EDIT:**
Create a div to put the result in:

```
<div id='result'></div>

var url = "http://hits.sinajs.cn/A1/weiboshare.html?' + temp.join('&');
$.get(url, function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);
});
```

In this way you can get the html from the server without having the complication of an iframe.
Then you can read the data from the div

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div">

</div>
```

then insert the newly data in this div inside ajax success callback  and then try this-

```
var htmlAfterChange = $('#div').html();
alert(htmlAfterChange );
```

Answer (score 0):

set **cache:false**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/